Create task definition AWS ECS, using versions in aws CDK Typescript
I need create a task definition using AWS CDK, my code is below:
const fargateTaskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, `${task.name}-${task.workspace}`, {
  memoryLimitMiB: task.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].memory,
  cpu: task.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].cpu,
  ephemeralStorageGiB: task.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].ephemeralStorageGiB,
  family: task.taskDefinition.family
});

const secrets: { [key: string]: ecs.Secret } = {};

Object.entries(parameterStore.parameters).forEach(([key, parameter]) => {
  secrets[key] = ecs.Secret.fromSsmParameter(parameter);
});
fargateTaskDefinition.addToExecutionRolePolicy(executionRolePolicy);
const container = fargateTaskDefinition.addContainer(task.name, {
  image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry(task.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].image),
  logging: ecs.LogDrivers.awsLogs({ streamPrefix: task.stack }),
  memoryLimitMiB: task.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].memory,
  secrets: secrets
});

container.addPortMappings({
  containerPort: task.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].portMappings[0].containerPort
});

const new_task = ecs.TaskDefinition.fromTaskDefinitionAttributes(this, `${task.name}-${task.workspace}-task`, {
  taskDefinitionArn: fargateTaskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn
});

But when I create a second env in secrets, AWS CDK deactivated my actual task and create other, example: version 1 activated, when version 2 join, version one is obsolete.
I need create version using AWS CDK in my task definitions.
